# Arel Aggregations, Count, Outer Join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have a `Fact` model, which `has_many` `:votes`.  Votes also have a `user_id` field.
I'd like to express the following in a scope for the `Fact` model: Give me all Facts which have 0 votes with a `user_id` equal to X.

I'm not quite familiar enough with Arel to understand how I might tackle this.  Ideas?

Comment: what is arel? can you post a link?

Comment: @Sam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770415/what-exactly-is-arel-in-rails-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem with the following scope:

```
  scope :not_voted_on_by_user, lambda {|user_id| select("distinct `facts`.*").joins("LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `facts`.id = `votes`.fact_id").where(["votes.user_id != ? OR votes.user_id IS NULL",user_id])}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class Fact < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_user, lambda { |id| joins(:user).where('users.id == ?', id).readonly(false)    }
  scope :vote_count, lambda { |count| where('? == (select count(fact_id) from votes where votes.fact_id == facts.id)', count)}
end

Fact.by_user(1).vote_count(0)
```

The vote_count scope is a bit sqly but you can chain these finders however you like, you can also see the underlying sql with:

```
Fact.by_user(1).vote_count(0).to_sql
```

And further to your comment, you might do the same in pure Arel by first declaring the Relations:

```
f = Arel::Table.new(:facts)
v = Arel::Table.new(:votes)
u = Arel::Table.new(:users)
```

Then composing the query and rendering it to sql.

```
sql = f.join(u).on(f[:user_id].eq(1)).where('0 == (select count(fact_id) from votes where votes.fact_id == facts.id)').to_sql
```

*You can act on columns with operators:* `f[:user_id].eq(1)`

Then using it:

```
Fact.find_by_sql(sql)
```

I'm sure theres a lot more that you could do to get a more elegant syntax (without the 'where 0 == ...' ). Also I'm pretty sure Rails3 scopes use Arel behind the scenes - http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: Yeah, this is similar to what I am doing now; my question is how to do this using Arel, or at least active relation.  Also, as a quibble, the user_id field described in this scenario belongs to the Vote model.