# Union of two scopes results in NoMethodError (undefined method `default_scoped?' ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have defined the following two scopes and both working fine:

```
scope :regular_friends, lambda { |user| joins{friendships}.where{friendships.user_id.not_in(user)}}
scope :inverse_friends, lambda { |user| joins{inverse_friendships}.where{inverse_friendships.friend_id.not_in(user)}}
```

I using squeel (https://github.com/ernie/squeel) here and building a self referential association, which is inspired by (http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

Based on that, I want to define a third scope which unions the results of the other two:

```
scope :friends, lambda { |user| User.regular_friends(user).union(User.inverse_friends(user)) }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I am getting a:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `default_scoped?' for #<Arel::Nodes::Union:0x8249534>):
```

I am on **Rails 3.1.3**. I thought the **default_scope?** method has been removed in Rails 3.*, but it's complaining about that...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method as `union` in Rails (I don't know about Arel). Just construct the scope as you would normally.

**EDIT**:
You can always use raw sql in the scope definition. I don't know the details of your application (especially how the tables are interconnected), so I can't construct the query in its full beauty. Nevertheless, the query will look similar to this:

```
scope :friends, find_by_sql(%(
  SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN friendships f on f.user_id = users.#{id} WHERE ...
  UNION
  SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN inverse_friendships i on i.friend_id = users.#{id} WHERE ...
)
```

Comment: Arel provides an Arel::Nodes:Union and found some examples using union() method, so I guess there is one. Anyway, I am not sure how to design the friends scope to return union of the other scopes in the normal way.

Comment: you can always use raw sql in the scope definition (and I guess that would be the way to if you want the union)

Answer (score 3):

`default_scope?` indeed is removed from Rails 3 and later.
I do not know why this error pops up (I have the same problem), but using `union()` in scopes seems not to work. Using them directly (outside `scope`) seems to work:

```
User.regular_friends(user).union(User.inverse_friends(user))
```

Personally, I do not put the union in a scope and directly use it (luckily I only us it on one place, so for me it is not a big deal).

I can also not use `union()` directly with `find()`, `first()`, `all()`, etc. I guess [arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770415/what-exactly-is-arel-in-rails-3-0) is not yet complete... To circumvent this problem I use:

```
sql = User.regular_friends(user).union(User.inverse_friends(user)).to_sql
result = find_by_sql(sql)
```

But maybe/probably there are nicer ways to prevent this...? (like waiting for an arel update :P )

Comment: It should be noted that this issue has been open in Arel since 2012 and is still open. I wouldn't expect a fix anytime soon.

Comment: might the https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union gem help, which defines `union` on `ActiveRecord::Query` to return `ActiveRecord::Query`?