# Calling specific instances of a user's objects on their show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to list a user's wanted ads in their show page when they access /users/:id.

In my controller I have:

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @wanted_ads = WantedAd.where(:user_id => params[:id])
```

And in my show.html.erb I have:

```
<%= @wanted_ads %>
```

Binding.pry says @wanted_ads is nil. On the actual page I get `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fa3b5a93408>`. This is seemingly a simple thing I'm trying to do -- what am I missing?

Comment: You should use relations for this. A user `has_many` wanted_ads. More info here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Got that part in already. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

The `where` function returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation`.
So, you can call `first` to get the first element, `last` to get the last one or `all` to get all elements stored in an array called @wanted_ads.

```
@wanted_ads = WantedAd.where(:user_id => params[:id]).all
```

You can then go through this array and choose the attributes you want to pass to the view for each element.

Just a tip:

You should have in your User model an ActiveRecord relation, like this:

```
has_many :wanted_ads
```

And in your WantedAd model, like this:

```
belongs_to :user
```

And with this, you have a relation of one-to-may.

Then, you can do this:

```
def show
    @user = User.includes(:wanted_ads).find(params[:id])
end
```

And then, in your view:

```
<% @user.wanted_ads.each do |wanted_ad| %>
    <%# do something %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`where` returns a collection of objects, not just a single object. So depending on what's returned you'll want to either call `first` to get the single instance that ought to return, or call `each` to iterate over the wanted ads and display them on your page.

You're seeing an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` in `pry` because of the underlying query mechanism that lazy loads the results. [More details can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770648/33226).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `@wanted_ads` is not nil and you want to loop through all the wanted ads...

```
<% @wanted_ads.each do |wanted_ad| %>

<%= wanted_ad.some_attribute_of_wanted_ad %>

<% end %>
```

I would also suggest you be aware of SQL injection with the following code in your controller.

```
@wanted_ads = WantedAd.where(:user_id => params[:id])
```

As it should be

```
@wanted_ads = WantedAd.where(":user_id => ?", params[:id])
```

Comment: No problem. Remember to check the answer that gave you the best help, whether it be mine or one of the other answers.