# How to scope with "where", "having" and "or"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I understand it is possible to do

```
scope :public_visible, where("(status = ?) OR (end_date > ?)", :published, Date.today)
```

But what I want to do is combining the following two scopes with **OR**

```
scope :succeeded, having("SUM(orders.sum) >= goal")
scope :ongoing, where("end_date >= ?", Date.today)
```

Is this possible? Either in sql or activerecord ways.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but I ended up doing

```
scope :succeeded_or_ongoing, where("id in (?) or id in (?)", Project.succeeded.map(&:id), Project.ongoing.map(&:id))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ARel ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770415/what-exactly-is-arel-in-rails-3-0)) in my honest opinion. You would have something like:

```
def succeeded_or_ongoing
  where("id in (?) or id in (?)", Project.succeeded.map(&:id), Project.ongoing.map(&:id))
end
```

Then do `Project.succeeded_or_ongoing`