# Find the 5 longest names in ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord

Let's say I have an articles table with thousands of articles. I am trying to figure out the most performant way to find the 5 longest article names, not the articles themselves.

This is what I have so far:

```
def self.five_longest_article_names
  limit(5).order("(LENGTH(name)) desc").pluck(:name)
end
```

But that uses SQL. Is there an ActiveRecord query that I could have performed instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
YourModel.limit(5).order("CHAR_LENGTH(name) desc").pluck(:name)
```

So, your method becomes:

```
def self.five_longest_article_names
  limit(5).order("CHAR_LENGTH(name) desc").pluck(:name)
end
```

You could defintely use `Arel`, but `Arel`s are good for complex queries. In your case, this is a simple usecase, and I think it's better to use `SQL` in this particular case.

Comment: thanks! In simplest world... what's the difference between Arel and AR?

Comment: In short, `Arel` is a SQL AST manager for Ruby. It `Simplifies the generation of complex SQL queries`. 
And, `Active Record` is the M in MVC - the model - which is the layer of the system responsible for representing business data and logic. `Active Record facilitates the creation and use of business objects` whose data requires persistent storage to a database.

Comment: `Arel` is a replacement for hand-crafting SQL queries in strings. See the accepted answer from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770415/what-exactly-is-arel-in-rails-3-0 to know more about Arel, what is it and what it is not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own name function for arel:

```
my_length = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('LENGTH', YourModel.table[:name])

YourModel.order(Arel::Nodes::Descending.new(my_length)).limit(5)
# or
YourModel.order("#{my_length.to_sql} DESC").limit(5)
```

I'd suggest you pass it as a named scope to your model and concatenate calls from there.